# sammy.js revert back to previous URL on error and 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, sammy.js

I would like to revert back to the previous URL when there is problem with routing in sammy.js.

There are 2 possible routing problems: a problem with a defined route and a 404 error.

It also seems that when you hit a 404 error, sammy.js then ignores the 404 URL and does not run the notFound function again - until another working route has been used.

If the user misses the initial 404 notification, they will keep clicking with frustration and think something is wrong.

I am hoping that reverting back to the previous URL will force sammy.js to retry again and again, re-informing the user that there is a problem.

Here is my existing code:

```
// custom error handler
var errorHandler = function (response) {
    viewModel.isLoading(false);
    toastr.error(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);                  
};

// not found override for routes that have not been defined
this.notFound = function () {
    toastr.error("404 Not Found");
}

// user route
this.get('/#/users/:id', function (context) {
    amplify.store('state.active-hash', this.path, { expires: config.storeExpiration });
    this.title(config.rootTitle + 'Edit User');
    context.load('/users/' + context.params.id, { error: errorHandler, cache: false }).swap(function () { replaceBindings(viewModel.editUser); });
});
```